# VBA Object Required error in Do While loop

Tags: vba, loops, excel, object, type-mismatch

I'm trying to write a peace of VBA code that will filter the selected month from a table. If the user doesn't give an answer to the month question, I want a loop in there that keeps asking the question until an answer is given. Preferable even with as only option 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, but I'm just a beginner in VBA.

I have written the following code so far:

```
Sub BE_NL_AddressBirthdaySplit()
'
' BE_NL_AddressBirthdaySplit Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w
'
    Dim bdaymonth As String
     bdaymonth = "0"

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:= _
    "BE-PM Benelux BVBA"
    bdaymonth = InputBox("What Month would you like to filter?", "Month of Birth")
Do While bdaymonth Is "0"
If bdaymonth = "" Then
result = MsgBox("You didn't specify the month", vbCritical, "No Month")
Else: ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1 _
    :=bdaymonth
End If
Loop

End Sub
```

But it keep giving me a "type mismatch" error in

```
Do While bdaymonth Is "0"
```

I have tried some ways. If I try this I get an "Object required error":

```
Sub BE_NL_AddressBirthdaySplit()
'
' BE_NL_AddressBirthdaySplit Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w
'
Dim bdaymonth As Variant


ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:= _
    "BE-PM Benelux BVBA"
    bdaymonth = InputBox("What Month would you like to filter?", "Month of Birth")
Do While bdaymonth Is Null
If bdaymonth = "" Then
result = MsgBox("You didn't specify the month", vbCritical, "No Month")
Else: ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1 _
    :=bdaymonth
End If
Loop

End Sub
```

I'm pretty new to VBA programming, could some of you give me some pointers to where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compare the strings wrongly. You should do this:

```
Do While bdaymonth = "0"
```

i.e. use `=` and not `Is`.

Also, when you want to compare a string against "null", you should do this:

```
Do While bdaymonth = vbNullString
```

Comment: To clarify: the "Is" operator checks if a certain object is of a certain type (eg: "hello" is string will return true). 

@djikay: good hint. You should never initialize a string as "0" as your default value.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the errors, but now when I type in something in the inputbox, it doesn't filter the file anymore. It just does nothing and ends the Sub.

Comment: @Casz146: Your `Do While` loop only matches if your string is "0" but just inside your loop you have an `If` that matches if the string is "". Clearly the second check will never happen. String "0" is not a null or empty string, it's a string with a single character "0" in it.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot! It's working now. Would it also be possible to get only the specific options in there? Or would I need to resort to a UserForm then?

Comment: The `InputBox` doesn't take a lot of customisation. It's just a simple request to the user to enter a string and then it returns it. If you want to add some logic to the input, then yes, you'd need a userform.

Comment: @Recipe `Is` is not for comparing types (`"hello" is String` is not even valid code), but for comparing objects. Ex: `Sheet1 is Sheet1` returns True but `Sheet1 is Sheet2` returns False

Comment: @z̫͋ thanks for the clarification. Guess I was a bit confused with C# ;-)